# Add entry in relation table when adding Contact

Tags: sugarcrm

I have set one to many relationship from Contacts to my Custom module.

Also have coded that when i add a contact one entry is also added in the table of custom module.

However when I add a new record the record is not inserted in the relationship table but when i update the record a record is inserted therein.

I want that even when I add a record its entry should go into the relationship table.

Comment: Post your code and describe how you've implemented. I assume logic hooks, but want to be sure... If it's a before_save hook, you probably need it to be after-save, or to set an ID and new_with_id=true (you can't easily create relationships to records that don't exist yet). But I'm just guessing.

Comment: YEs its a before_save logic hook.Actually what I want is when I insert/update  a record in Contacts or any other module an entry is also saved in other module.I have done this however in my custom module the inserted record when clicked should open actual record(Contact).And the same should happen when I create reports for them.